# How to run 2 functions working with API in telegram bot?

Tags: python, bots, telegram, telegram-bot, python-multithreading

I created bot. It can handle some commands in chat and for working this part of him I use

```py
def runBot():
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=1, timeout=30, long_polling_timeout=65)
```

and there is another part of bot, where I am getting updates on all incoming messages (I added bot in some chat) with:

```py
def getUpdates():
    ...
    MethodGetUpdates = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{BOT_TOKEN}/getUpdates'
    offsetParam = {'offset': offset, 'allowed_updates': ['message']}
    response = requests.get(MethodGetUpdates, offsetParam)
    ...
```

(I calculate offset)

BUT I can make this parts work only separately, not together. That is the problem.

I found out that I can use "threading", so I write this:

```py
def runBot():
    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=1, timeout=30, long_polling_timeout=65)

def runScheluders():
    schedule.every(70).seconds.do(getUpdates)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    t1 = threading.Thread(target=runBot)
    t2 = threading.Thread(target=runScheluders)
    t1.start()
    t2.start()
```

and it does not work(
In this station bot answers to commands, but getUpdates does not see new messages and returning:

> '{'ok': True, 'result': []}'

And if I comment in function 'main' t1 or t2, another one works perfect. But I want them to work together. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Where does the `bot.polling` come from?

Comment: Sorry for your time. I figured out that i dont need getUpdates and polling at the same time. Becouse it is the same. So i am using just polling now and everything is ok